# Cannot get subprocess return code in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to make something like supervisor for my python daemon process and found out that same code works in python2 and doesn't work in python3.

Generally, I've come to this minimal example code.

**daemon.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import signal
import sys
import os


def stop(*args, **kwargs):
    print('daemon exited', os.getpid())
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)

print('daemon started', os.getpid())

while True:
    pass
```

**supervisor.py**

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

from time import sleep


parent_pid = os.getpid()
commands = [
    [
        './daemon.py'
    ]
]
popen_list = []
for command in commands:
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    popen_list.append(popen)


def stop_workers(*args, **kwargs):
    for popen in popen_list:
        print('send_signal', popen.pid)
        popen.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)

        while True:
            popen_return_code = popen.poll()
            if popen_return_code is not None:
                break
            sleep(5)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop_workers)

for popen in popen_list:
    print('wait_main', popen.wait())
```

If you run supervisor.py and then call `kill -15` on its pid, then it will hang in infinite loop, because popen_return_code will never be not None. I discovered, that it's basically because of adding threading.Lock for wait_pid operation ([source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/subprocess.py#l1311)), but how can I rewrite code so it'll handle child exit correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting case.

I've spent few hours trying to figure out the reason why this happens and the only thing I came up with at this moment is that the implementation of `wait()` and `poll()` have been changed in `python3` versus `python2.7`.

Looking into the source code of `python3/suprocess.py` implementation, we can see that there is a lock acquire happens when you call `wait()` method of `Popen` object, see

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1402.

This lock prevents further `poll()` calls to work as expected until the lock acquired by `wait()` will be released, see

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1355

and comment there

> Something else is busy calling waitpid.  Don't allow two
>   at once.  We know nothing yet.

There is no such a lock in `python2.7/subprocess.py` so this looks like a reason why it works in `python2.7` and doesn't work in `python3`.

However I don't see a reason why are you trying to `poll()` inside the signal handler, try rewrite your `supervisor.py` as following, this should work as expected both on `python3` and `python2.7`

**supervisor.py**

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

from time import sleep


parent_pid = os.getpid()
commands = [
    [
        './daemon.py'
    ]
]
popen_list = []
for command in commands:
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    popen_list.append(popen)


def stop_workers(*args, **kwargs):
    for popen in popen_list:
        print('send_signal', popen.pid)
        popen.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop_workers)

for popen in popen_list:
    print('wait_main', popen.wait())
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I don't handle child exist and just send SIGTERM, then when my child doesn't implement handler (try to delete `sys.exit` from `daemon.py`), it will just detached to init process.

Comment: for popen in popen_list:
    print('wait_main', popen.wait())

Comment: Sorry for messy comments :(

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I agree with answer from @risboo6909, but also have some thoughts, how to fix this situation.

1. You can change `subproccess.Popen` to `psutil.Popen`.
2. In main loop instead of `popen.wait()` you can just do infinite loop, because process will exit in signal handler.